# Call a custom php function in header of wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have defined a custom function in functions.php., And I want to call it in header, exactly as `<meta name="description" content="<?php meta_desc(); ?>">`.
But I am seeing empty meta description when I view source code. This custom function works well If I use it somewhere else.

Comment: show us the code in functions.php

Comment: `<?php echo meta_desc(); ?>`?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto That worked... Can you post it in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you :

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo meta_desc(); ?>">
```